# Chrome Unpacked Extension Disappears

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently developing a Chrome Extension, i test it as an unpacked extension in dev mode, normally the extension remains connected when restarting chrome, however suddenly it is removed every-time i close chrome with no explanation or indication that something is wrong with my extension

Any ideas what went wrong, or why this may happen?

Thanks

Comment: does not happen on any of my local extensions or apps. seems an issue with your chrome, and not a coding issue.

Comment: I have currently the same problem, it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me, after having lost 2 days trying almost *everything*:

1. export your bookmarks...
2. uninstall CHROME
3. **delete** C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\
4. install CHROME

Comment: Great That Worked!! so annoying i was also debugging my code for hours!.. No uninstall required, i just deleted the user files.. Thanks :).. whats strange was it happened on two computers, and it was after playing around with chrome storage..

Answer (score 1):

Much time has passed since this post but for any looking - but I hit a less drastic solution - there was a hint elsewhere that the key entry in the manifest might be the problem so I deleted it entirely and reloaded it unpacked... works. I'll likely need to get another key at some point but for now its fine for dev.

Comment: Or move the extension into another folder (rename folder). It will assign new ID to the extension. So now is the question, why this happening?