# Unpacked extension uninstalls automatically every time when Chrome is restarted, how can I have it always installed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

[Chrome Unpacked Extension Disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594336/chrome-unpacked-extension-disappears)

I Google this for a long while and only find this link above. However, it doesn't solve my problem.

I am on Mac. And I don't want to uninstall Chrome. Is there any settings that I'm missing?

Comment: It means you've previously installed the same extension with a different `"key"` in manifest.json or you installed a different extension from the same source directory. In both cases Chrome retains an entry in its `Secure Preferences` file inside the profile. The only way to fix this is to install that old extension (or use that old `"key"`), then remove it explicitly so Chrome forgets it. Well, there's another way - you can edit the secure preferences file manually and remove the wrong extension entry and recalculate its hash which is really hackish so google up those articles/tools yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I did adjust the key file because I want to use a fixed key to access the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` api. If I lost the old extension and I don't want to make changes to the security settings, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

same issue - I removed the "key" entry from the manifest altogether, reloaded it unpacked  and that worked. We'll see what happens when I get to register it but I suspect I'll get get another key